# Joining three tables and grouping

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm quite new to SQL and php etc so apologies for that.
I have three tables, content, author_content and authors. I am using an SQL statement to get this json data

```
----------------------
|authorId | contentId|
|--------------------|
|1        |1         |
|1        |2         |
|2        |2         |
|2        |3         |
|3        |4         |
----------------------
```

But I want it to look like this, where each author is grouped with all of their content.

---

```
|authorId | contentId|
|--------------------|
|1        |1,2       |
|2        |1,3       |
|3        |4         |
----------------------
```

I am unsure if this is possible using SQL and was thinking their might be a better PHP solution.
SQL statement I am using:

```
SELECT authors.authorId, content.contentId
FROM content
INNER JOIN content_authors
      ON content_authors.contentId = content.contentId
INNER JOIN authors
      ON content_authors.authorId = authors.authorId
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GROUP BY, and group_concat(?, or similar.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `group_concat` to collect all contentId in each group of authorId:

```
SELECT authors.authorId, GROUP_CONCAT(content.contentId)
FROM content
INNER JOIN content_authors
      ON content_authors.contentId = content.contentId
INNER JOIN authors
      ON content_authors.authorId = authors.authorId
GROUP BY authors.authorId
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to join. You can get the result you want directly fro bridge table `content_author`:

```
select authorid, group_concat(contentid) as contentids
from content_author
group by authorid
```

Comment: the tables `content` and `author` may only contain a subset of those in the bridge table...? e.g. there is only 1 row in `author` and in `content` but lots of rows in the bridge table, in which case your query could return many rows ?

Comment: @mck: such a schema usually have foreign key constraints from the bridge table to the referential tables, so there are no "orphan" records in the bridge table. If so, the query is guaranteed to return the same result as the solution with two joins, and, of course, is more efficient.